# Display users in firebase except the current logged-in user

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to display the list of all users in the collection except the currently logged-in user but the code I have and any that I found online always give the same answer which keeps on showing the currently logged user. I am looking for another solution and code to help fix the issue.
I even tried to add a slice in there but it didn't work because it followed the order of collection or the name list order.

I think I am trying to take the list of all users inside the Firebase collection and then display them in my react-native app for multiple purposes for instance when I want to follow that user or when trying to call that user. Still, the issue here is that the current user or (ME) as a user currently signed-in should not appear instead other users only should be listed. I hope this clarifies the misunderstanding.

Here's the piece of code that I tried

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    const delay = 1000
    setIsLoading(true)

    const loadingTime = setTimeout(()=> {

      const current_userVal = user.uid
      const unsub = db.collection('users').onSnapshot((snap) => {
        const listUsers = [];
        snap.forEach((doc) => {
          const userData = doc.data();
          //console.log(user.uid)
  
          if (users && user.uid != doc.id) {
            
            listUsers.push({ id: doc.id, ...userData });
          }
        })
      
        const newList = listUsers.slice(current_userVal)
        if (currentUserUid) {
          
        }
        setUsers(newList)
         setIsLoading(false)
      });

      return () => {
         unsub()
         clearTimeout(loadingTime)
       };
    }, delay)

  }, [])
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger, so I recommend debugging the code locally and telling us the result. Set a breakpoint on `if (users && user.uid != doc.id) {`, and then run in the debugger. Check the variables on the line when the debug hit, as one of them is likely not what you/the code expects it to be.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using a Firebase library like `react/fire` or similar. If so, I recommend you using the provided functions which in your case would be `.where()` when querying from your Firestore instance.

Try avoiding native functions for arrays if you have libraries dedicated for this. For **your use-case** the query should look something like this:

```js
// We use Firebase dedicated functions to directly filter and sort the requested data as we are sending the request.

const users$ = this.db.collection<User>('users', (ref) => ref.where('id', '!=', '<your user id as string>'))
```